# How does drush:site-install recognize a previous civi installation?

Tags: installation, drupal-9, 5.10.x

While trying to set up an install script for a composer drupal/civi template, I try to rerun the install process several times. CiviCRM refuses to do that, saying

```
civicrm appears to have already been installed. skipping full installation.
```

I know that. But I've cleared all tables from the database, and I've cleared `web/sites/default/files/civicrm*`. It still says that. What is it seeing ?

The message is generated from `./web/modules/contrib/civicrm/civicrm.install` which reads

```
if ($installed->isSettingInstalled() || $installed->isDatabaseInstalled()) {
    throw new \Exception("CiviCRM appears to have already been installed. Skipping full installation.");
  }
```

.. but what is it looking at ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also looks for civicrm.settings.php and there's also a civicrm_install_canary table.

Comment: I also removed `web/sites/default/files/civicrm.settings.php` and even the dist file, it still recognizes it.

Comment: Did you also clear the civicrm_install_canary db table?

Comment: the WHUT ? :-D no.

Comment: Confirmed: removing civicrm.settings.php and killing the canary works.